# SQL injection from an Active Directory

Tags: php, sql, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem I don't understand. I want to make a php script which will fill some sql's tables from an Active Directory.

Here is a part of my code :

    `$result=ldap_list($connect, "OU=PROFS,".$base_dnref, "(ou=*)");`

```
$res = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);

for ($i=0; $i < $res["count"]; $i++) {
$result2=ldap_list($connect, "OU=".$res[$i]["ou"][0].",OU=PROFS,".$base_dnref, "(cn=*)");
$res2 = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result2);
for($j=0;$j<$res2["count"];$j++){

    $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO PROFESSEURS(NOM) VALUES ('".$res2[$j]["cn"][0]."')");
    $insert->fetch();
}
}




$result=ldap_list($connect, "OU=ELEVES,".$base_dnref, "(ou=*)");

$res = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);

for ($z=0; $z < $res["count"]; $z++) {

$insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO CLASSE(NUMERO) VALUES ('".strval($res[$z]["ou"][0])."')");
$insert->fetch();

$result2=ldap_list($connect, "OU=".$res[$z]["ou"][0].",OU=ELEVES,".$base_dnref, "(cn=*)");
$res2 = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result2);

for($y=0;$y<$res2["count"];$y++){

    $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO ELEVE(NOM) VALUES ('".$res2[$y]["cn"][0]."')");
    $insert->fetch();

}
}



}
catch (PDOException $e) {
   print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}`
```

The matter is that the first double `for` works perfectly, but the second doesn't. However I used the same syntax. The error is : "Exception : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error".

Additionaly, the query `$insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO CLASSE(NUMERO) VALUES ('".strval($res[$z]["ou"][0])."')");` works fine but only with half of the Active Directory datas, the other not at all. I'm sure that the problem doesn't come from the LDAP path, I use LDAPExplorerTool for this.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below code with yours:

```
$res = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);

for ($i=0; $i < $res["count"]; $i++) {
$result2=ldap_list($connect, "OU=".$res[$i]["ou"][0].",OU=PROFS,".$base_dnref, "(cn=*)");
$res2 = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result2);
        for($j=0;$j<$res2["count"];$j++){
                $NOM = $res2[$j]["cn"][0];//Store value into variable for further use...
            $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO PROFESSEURS(NOM) VALUES ('".$NOM."')");
            $insert->fetch();
        }
}

$result=ldap_list($connect, "OU=ELEVES,".$base_dnref, "(ou=*)");

$res = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);

for ($z=0; $z < $res["count"]; $z++) {
        $NUMERO = strval($res[$z]["ou"][0]);//Store value into variable for further use...
        $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO CLASSE(NUMERO) VALUES ('".$NUMERO."')");
        $insert->fetch();

        $result2=ldap_list($connect, "OU=".$res[$z]["ou"][0].",OU=ELEVES,".$base_dnref, "(cn=*)");
        $res2 = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result2);

        for($y=0;$y<$res2["count"];$y++){
                $NOM = $res2[$y]["cn"][0];//Store value into variable for further use...
            $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO ELEVE(NOM) VALUES ('".$res2[$y]["cn"][0]."')");


            $insert->fetch();

        }
}
```

I have made some slight changes where I have doubt. I suggest to use PDO statement because old one is now depreciated.

Let me know if you are still facing error, we can drill into it solve that problem.

Thanks!

Comment: On my browser, your script make a "Exception : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error". Only one row is filled in the database with the id 163, I find that quite strange.

Comment: Can you please comment this: $insert->fetch(); If its not required. Further, I am not facing "Exception : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error" on my system. 

Let me know if any changes.

Comment: I did but the same error appears when I run the script and only the PROFESSEURS table is filled. Even if there is an error, the code you propose before only fill the CLASSE table, I find this too random, I'm lost...

Comment: This "**Fatal error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error**" generate while mysql seems some problem to perform action over DB only. You need to check it manually by checking mysql error log(**mysql.log**) file. This error log give you some hint on mysql error.

Please check and let me know if there is more help from me.

Comment: Sorry for taking more of your time but i work only on phpmyadmin and when I go to the binary logs, I can't read anything. Can you tell me how to read them please ?

Comment: @arkodath: you can find it from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html OR http://www3.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/mysql/manual_Log_files.html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
It came from the syntax of the queries. I replace :

`$insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO ELEVE(NOM) VALUES ('".$res2[$y]["cn"][0]."')");
$insert->fetch();`

by : `$insert=$db->exec('INSERT INTO ELEVE(NOM) VALUES ("'.$res2[$y]["cn"][0].'")');`

So much time for this...